# How to get 4 random images and use as 4 related posts' thumbnails in Wordpress?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I would like to display 4 different images at related posts' thumbnails  on my page, that is picked randomly from the images in URLs.  However ,the thumbnails images are same for each related post.

I don't know how to add the different random image at each related posts to this code.

my PHP code:

```
<?php
/**
related posts
 */
$tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);
$images = array(
    'https://img-blog.com/20200916142100590.jpg',
    'https://img-blog.com/20200915155348194.jpg',
    'https://img-blog.com/20200910152002780.jpg',
);
$image_url = $images[array_rand( $images, 1 )];
if ($tags) {
$tag_ids = array();
foreach($tags as $individual_tag) $tag_ids[] = $individual_tag->term_id;
 
$args=array(
'tag__in' => $tag_ids,
'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
'showposts'=>4,  // Number of related posts that will be shown.
'caller_get_posts'=>1
);
 
$my_query = new wp_query($args);
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
echo '<div id="relatedposts"><h3>Related posts</h3><ul>';
while ($my_query->have_posts()) {
$my_query->the_post();
?>
  
<?php
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
<li><div class="relatedthumb"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?><?php the_title(); ?></a></div></li>
<?php } else { ?>
<li><div class="relatedthumb"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image_url ?>" width="196" height="110" alt="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" /><?php the_title(); ?></a></div></li>
<?php }
?>
  
<?php
}
echo '</ul>';
}
}
$post = $backup;
wp_reset_query();
/**
 end
 */
?>
```

[my related posts' thumbnails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8P7c5.png)

Comment: Pick a random image _inside_ the loop, instead of doing that only once, before …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the following line inside your loop, instead of outside of the loop. So it will randomize the link every-time.

```
while ($my_query->have_posts()) {
```

**$image_url = $images[array_rand( $images, 1 )];**